# How to disable headless mode in java (using eclipse luna, fedora 21)

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

Today I installed Fedora 21 and when I tried to compile my java project in eclipse, I got a java.awt.HeadLessException. I want to disable the headless mode but i don't know how.

EDIT: I Solved it installing jre7 and changing it in the build path, I was using jre8.

Comment: -Djava.awt.headless=[true|false] as a vm arg in eclipse.ini

Comment: I tried that and it didn't worked